# On anchor click stop redirecting page and display alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have one anchor which is downloading file from server in servlet and jsp.

Now I have one problem occurred that before downloading file if there is any error occurred it is redirects and shows error(which is customized error message by me) on new page. And through ajax call we can't download file, so this is not solution for me.

So is it any solution available that stops redirects to another page and display error message on  alert by clicking on anchor?

Comment: I only want to stop redirecting if there are any error comes from server.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this JQuery plugin [jquery-file-download-plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)  and here is the [demo](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)  page of this plugin. its inserting iframe dynamically to DOM and produces look and feel just like AJAX request. It might be helpful for you. but on server side you have to add a cookie which will trigger its success and failure callback

**Usage on Client Side:**

```
$.fileDownload(url,{                 
               successCallback: function (url)      
           {        
                   console.log("File Downloaded");   

           },       
           failCallback: function (html, url) 
            {    
               console.log("Error in File Download");   

            } 

    });
```

and on server side if you are using java add cookie like this

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("fileDownload", "true");
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

and in case of fail

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("fileDownload", "false");
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

**EDIT**

you have to implement javascript method on anchor click in which you have to add the above code. the above coed is `GET` request.

Comment: +1 for giving me possible solution, Seems like there is no other option than this. Let's see. Thank you.

Comment: yup, to handle errors and to stop redirection you go for ajax, but when you go for ajax, file download becomes and issue.